# Microsoft Graph (OneDrive) API - Resumable Upload Content-Type

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to create the upload PUT request for the OneDrive API. It's the large file "resumable upload" version which requires the createUploadSession.

I have read the Microsoft docs here: [As a warning the docs are VERY inaccurate and full of factual errors...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)

The docs simply say:

> PUT
> https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337
> Content-Length:
> 26
> Content-Range: bytes 0-25/128
>  <bytes 0-25 of the
> file>

I am authenticated and have the upload session created, however when I pass the JSON body containing my binary file I receive this error:

> {   "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": "Property file in payload has a value that does not match schema.",    .....

Can anyone point me at the schema definition? Or explain how the JSON should be constructed?

As a side question, am I right in using "application/json" for this at all? What format should the request use?

Just to confirm, I am able to see the temp file created ready and waiting on OneDrive for the upload, so I know I'm close.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to keep in mind that your app must ensure the total file size specified in the Content-Range header is the same for all requests. If a byte range declares a different file size, the request will fail. So, I would try something like this:

PUT https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337
Content-Length: 26
Content-Range: bytes 0-25/128

<bytes 0-25 of the file>

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm not trying to upload in chunks. I'm putting the entire file in a single request. The real question is what is the correct JSON schema. Also, is application/json the correct Content-Type?

Answer (score 2):

If you're uploading the entire file in a single request then why do you use upload session when you can use the simple `PUT` request?

`url = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{user_id}/items/{parent_folder_ref_id}:/{filename}:/content`
and `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` header  and in body simply put the file `bytes`.

If for some reason I don't understand you have to use single-chunk upload session then:

1. Create upload session (you didn't specified any problems here so i'm not elaborating)
2. Get `uploadUrl` from `createUploadSession` response and send `PUT` request with the following headers:

   2.1 `"Content-Length": str(file_size_in_bytes)`

   2.2 `"Content-Range": "bytes 0-{file_size_in_bytes - 1}/{file_size_in_bytes}"`

   2.3 `"Content-Type": "text/plain"`
3. Pass the file bytes in body.

Note that in the `PUT` request the body is not `json` but simply `bytes` (as specified by the `content-type` header.

Also note that max chuck size is 4MB so if your file is larger than that, you will have to split into more than one chunks.

Goodlcuk

Comment: Hi Noam, thanks for your reply.

It’s my understanding that the simple PUT version of the file upload is limited to 4MB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

However, the "Upload large files with an upload session" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0 has a max file size of 60MB which is enough for me to upload in a single chunk.
My files are >4MB & <60MB.

I’m very grateful for the Content-Type info and will try that today.

Comment: I also appear to have no idea how to format comments .. sorry:-(

Comment: Ok, so I tried to make the content type "text/plain" and the API error returned was: "{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header."," ... @Noam Are you sure this content-type is correct for resumable uploads?

Comment: I should mention that I am trying to upload to a OneDrive for Business account not a personal one ...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, that's really weird. I'm doing the same thing in my code and it's working, not sure what to say. If you do solve it, please share here how you mange to do so.. goodluck

Comment: The last note did it for me, my file was slightly over 4MB so I assumed just using the session would be enough, however splitting it into chunks solved the issue